# Set cookie in browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser, session-cookies

I have a cookie and i need to set the cookie in a browser. I tried using the below code but the cookie was not set to the webpage. How this can be done using javascript.I need to set cookie in the browser like this

[image]

I tried using the below code

```
document.cookie = 'JSESSIONID=' + e + expires + ';path=/geoserver;' + 'domain=http://localhost:8080/geoserver';
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie, and note this, referring to using `document.cookie = `: "Note that you can only set/update a single cookie at a time using this method."

Comment: You **cannot** create a cookie for arbitrary domain. Only for domain your script belongs to.

Comment: I am creating cookie for my domain only.

Comment: Then you may remove `domain` part since it doesn't make sense